# How to start Nginx server within alpine image using rc-service command

Tags: docker, nginx, service, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to create my own `Nginx` image, using `apline:3.12.0` image, after fixing a lot of errors, thanks to the internet, I managed to do it and everything works fine, but the problem is when I run the following command :

```
rc-service nginx status
 * status: stopped
```

and when I try to start the service this is what it gives me as shown below :

```
rc-service nginx start
 * WARNING: nginx is already starting
```

even though the service is stopped the output of the second command tells it is already started?!

so I opened the localhost of my docker-machine to verify whether the service is on or off, and the nginx html page appears successfully.

I tried to run `rc-service nginx reload` and this is the result:

```
rc-service nginx reload
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 100: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/tasks: Read-only file system
 * nginx: cannot `reload' as it has not been started
```

here is the output of `nginx -t` :

```
nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

and here is the output of `less /var/log/nginx/error.log` as shown below there is no error :

```
less: can't open '/var/log/nginx/error.log': No such file or directory
```

this is my dockerfile :

```
From alpine:latest

COPY nginx.conf ./tmp
COPY index.html ./tmp
COPY run.bash ./tmp
COPY run2.bash ./tmp

RUN apk update && \
    apk add nginx && \
    adduser -D -g 'www' www && \
    mkdir /www && \
    chown -R www:www /var/lib/nginx && \
    chown -R www:www /www && \
    mv /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.orig && \
    apk add openrc --no-cache && \
    sh tmp/run.bash

cmd sh tmp/run2.bash
```

run.bash :

```
mv tmp/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
mv tmp/index.html  /www/index.html
```

run2.bash :

```
mkdir /run/openrc
touch /run/openrc/softlevel
mkdir -p /run/nginx
nginx
sh
```

and this is the guide that I followed :

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Nginx

I want to know why `rc-service nginx reload` doesn't work even that my nginx service is running perfectly on my docker machine, and also why `rc-service nginx status` tells that the nginx service is stopped even that it is not ?

and thanks in advance.

By the way when I run this command `nginx -s reload`, it works without any errors.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After debugging and lots of trial and error, I found a perfect solution at least for me, **David Maze** answer is very helpful, But I need to be able to restart the nginx service within the container.

whatever when I start my container using the following command :

```
docker run -it -p 80:80 -p 443:443 alpine:3.12.0
```

we access the container shell, and we need to download `nginx` server , and `openrc` to be able to use `rc-service` command line.

```
/ # apk update
/ # apk add nginx openrc
```

**#ANSWER 1**

now we'll test If there is an error in nginx server by using the following command :

```
/ # nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] open() "/run/nginx/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

as you can see from the output that we get, It tells you that a missing file or directory shall be created, so let's create that directory :

```
/ # ls -la run/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Dec 16 10:31 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:12 ..

/ # mkdir /run/nginx/
```

and we give that directory that we created some permissions :

```
/ # chown -R nginx:nginx /run/nginx/
/ # chmod 775 /run/nginx/
/ # ls -la /run/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:15 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:12 ..
drwxrwxr-x    2 nginx    nginx         4096 Jan 16 08:15 nginx
```

now we are good with nginx :

```
/ # nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Let's test our nginx service is it started or not with `rc-service` command :

```
/ # rc-service nginx status
 * You are attempting to run an openrc service on a
 * system which openrc did not boot.
 * You may be inside a chroot or you may have used
 * another initialization system to boot this system.
 * In this situation, you will get unpredictable results!
 * If you really want to do this, issue the following command:
 * touch /run/openrc/softlevel
```

So from the above output we see that we have two problems, `openrc` did not boot, and there is a missing file `softlevel` :

```
/ # ls -la /run/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:15 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:12 ..
drwxrwxr-x    2 nginx    nginx         4096 Jan 16 08:22 nginx
```

Let's start by booting our system with `openrc` simply by typing it itself :

```
/ # openrc
 * Caching service dependencies ...
Service `hwdrivers' needs non existent service `dev'

/ # ls -la /run/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:12 ..
drwxrwxr-x    2 nginx    nginx         4096 Jan 16 08:22 nginx
drwxr-xr-x   14 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 openrc

/ # ls -la /run/openrc/
total 64
drwxr-xr-x   14 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 daemons
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            11 Jan 16 08:29 depconfig
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2895 Jan 16 08:29 deptree
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 exclusive
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 failed
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 hotplugged
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 inactive
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 options
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 scheduled
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 started
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 starting
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 stopping
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 tmp
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jan 16 08:29 wasinactive
```

now we create the missing file :

```
/ # touch /run/openrc/softlevel
```

now our `rc-service` command works perfectly :

```
/ # rc-service nginx status
 * status: stopped
```

let's start our server :

```
 / # rc-service nginx start
 * Starting nginx ...          [ ok ]
```

check if it is started or not :

```
/ # rc-service nginx status
 * status: started
```

**#ANSWER 2**

Or you can simply call those two command lines instead :

```
/ # openrc
 * Caching service dependencies ...
Service `hwdrivers' needs non existent service `dev'    [ ok ]

/ # touch /run/openrc/softlevel
```

Now you can start your nginx server :)

```
/ # rc-service nginx status
 * status: stopped

/ # rc-service nginx start
 * /run/nginx: creating directory
 * /run/nginx: correcting owner
 * Starting nginx ...         [ ok ]

/ # rc-service nginx status
 * status: started
```

Hope I was clear.

Comment: This should be part of the main wiki at https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Nginx
Thanks!

Comment: Hey Holy, thank you so much for the detailed answer. However we are facing error listed in this thread. Could you please help that why it is trying to setup networking?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/69218786/9548311

Answer (score 5):

A Docker container generally only runs a single process.  You don't need to "start a service" or "restart a service"; generally the server process itself is the main container process, and if you need to restart the service, you restart the entire container.  Often "service"-type commands are missing some key piece of infrastructure in a Docker context and just won't work.

In your Dockerfile, you can just make the main command be to launch Nginx as a foreground process

```sh
# No need for openrc
CMD nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

and then when you need to change the configuration, build a new image and recreate the container

```sh
docker build -t my-nginx .
docker stop nginx
docker rm nginx
docker run --name nginx -p 3333:80 -d my-nginx
```