# ERROR: cannot start nginx as networking would not start on alpine docker image

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, nginx-reverse-proxy, alpine-linux

We are trying to install and run nginx on java based alpine image (`anapsix/alpine-java:7_jdk`) but we are facing below error when we start it

```
rc-service nginx start
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/tasks: Read-only file system
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: line 250: can't create /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/tasks: Read-only file system
 * Starting networking ...
awk: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
 * ERROR: networking failed to start
 * ERROR: cannot start nginx as networking would not start
```

We have tried many articles but nowhere it is mentioned that how to fix networking issue with the nginx on this alpine based image. Even if we create `/etc/network/interfaces` file, we don't know what should be the correct values inside it. Below is what we are running Dockerfile

```
# Add Nginx
RUN apk --update add nginx openrc
RUN mkdir -p /run/nginx
RUN touch /run/nginx/nginx.pid
# RUN adduser -D -g 'nginx' nginx
# RUN mkdir /home/nginx
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/nginx
# RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /home/nginx
COPY birt.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/birt.conf
# COPY index.html /nginx
RUN openrc
RUN touch /run/openrc/softlevel
RUN rc-update add nginx default
```

Please help us to achieve this.

Comment: Maybe looking at how the official nginx image is built can help? https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/d496baf859613adfe391ca8e7615cc7ec7966621/mainline/alpine/Dockerfile

Comment: Hey Hans ... thanks for your suggestion but the steps given in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65734249/9548311 is almost same, still we are facing issues

Comment: why do you need the java base image?

Comment: Because we are running java/jboss based process birt in this docker. So we need to send some response header back which contains Host/pod ip address due to which we are trying to route traffic through nginx to the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get Nginx to work within `anapsix/alpine-java:7_jdk` image after seeing this amazing [answer](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/42#issuecomment-173825611).

Here is a working Dockerfile :

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:7_jdk

COPY script.bash .

RUN apk --update add nginx openrc
RUN openrc
RUN touch /run/openrc/softlevel

CMD bash ./script.bash
```

and here is the `script.bash` used in `CMD` :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Tell openrc loopback and net are already there, since docker handles the networking
echo 'rc_provide="loopback net"' >> /etc/rc.conf

# get inside the container bash
bash
```

after building the image using `docker build . -t nginx_alpine_java` run the following commands :

`docker run -it -p 80:80 nginx_alpine_java`

now we are inside our container bash

```
bash-4.3# rc-service nginx status
 * status: stopped

bash-4.3# rc-service nginx start
 * /run/nginx: creating directory
 * /run/nginx: correcting owner                                [ ok ]
 * Starting nginx ...                                          [ ok ]
```

I hope that it will work with you.

Comment: Hey Holy ... you are a life saver ... thanks for all the efforts. Its working now :)

Comment: @NitinGarg Wish you all the best.

Comment: OMG I've been searching for days to find this. I'm trying to start an Alpine linux container with openrc and the container wouldn't load networking in AWS FARGATE but it would locally in my Docker container running on a Mac. I've been searching high and low for the answer and this fixed it! Thank you!